# Make a Windows 10 service log on as an Azure AD user

Tags: windows, windows-10, azure-active-directory

I've got a VM running Windows 10 somewhere (with internet access). It is hooked up to Azure AD, and I can sign in with my domain credentials. Now I need to run a service as another user in Azure AD (it's actually a service account) since it's got all the correct permissions.

When I try to set it naively, I get an error about which says (approximately) that the domain is not in my list of locations.

Is there any way for me to do this?

Comment: If your vm is just AAD joined (no on-premise), you cannot add aad user in your vm. Because the vm only verify your aad joined user, it cannot verify your domain.

Comment: So Azure AD doesn't have a notion of domains? And Windows 10 can't start a service as a user in the domain, even if said user can log in through RDP? That would be stupid.